# GitLab Runner not starting process

Tags: windows, powershell, gitlab-ci-runner

I have configured a GitLab Runner to run on one of my computers (the computer is Windows and uses Powershell to run yml script commands).

For my repo I have configured the yml file to copy the contents of the build into another directory, then have the runner run: `Start-Process -FilePath "$PROJECTNAME.exe" -ArgumentList "$PROG_ARG_1"` after changing into that directory.

However, the pipeline succeeds but the process that has been started (using "Start-Process" above) cannot be found on the computer anywhere (has not actually been started).

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: it is running just as a "Background Process" (needed to open control panel to verify it)

Comment: How do you know it didn't start and then stop/crash?

Comment: Because I ran the exact same command manually and it worked. My problem is the same as this person here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4781 , however the solution isn't provided unfortunately.

Comment: As an aside: [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) creates a _new console_ and runs asynchronously by default. If you want an external console application to run synchronously in the same console, with its output reported to the calling PowerShell session, invoke it directly: `& "$PROJECTNAME.exe" $PROG_ARG_1`

Comment: But this will run synchronously with the runner itself... Which is not what I want since the application I am running is not terminating.

Comment: Nevermind I didn't check "Back Processes" turns out it was running all along.